# Path containing all the vertices in a biconnected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

You are given a biconnected graph. A graph in which more than one simple path exists between any two different nodes.

Suppose there are N vertices in the graph. Now you have to choose a starting point and an ending point from these N vertices(possibly same) and travel from starting point to the ending point such that all the vertices are visited atleast once but all the edges are visited atmost once. You have to tell whether such a path exists or not.

Comment: This condition is closely related to the property of being "supereulerian" (I guess this problem would be "has a spanning Eulerian or semi-Eulerian subgraph, whereas supereulerian is limited to "has a spanning Eulerian subgraph"). Catlin surveys the theory of supereulerian graphs: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/jgt.3190160209 . Nothing jumps out as obviously applicable in the special case of a biconnected graph.

Comment: What are the input constraints?

Comment: N <= 10^5. number of edges <= 10^5

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is NP-hard, via the following reduction from [Hamiltonian path on a biconnected cubic graph](https://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1183.html) inspired by Catlin's observation that in cubic graphs, having a Hamiltonian cycle is equivalent to having a spanning Eulerian circuit. The reduction just spits out the input graph. If the input graph has a Hamiltonian path, then that path is a spanning Eulerian trail (what the problem calls for us to look for). Conversely, suppose that we have a spanning Eulerian trail. There are three cases for the trail:

1. Two vertices with degree one in the trail; all other vertices have even degree.
2. All vertices have even degree.
3. Two vertices with degree three in the trail; all other vertices have even degree.

Case 1 immediately gives us a Hamiltonian path. Case 2 immediately gives us a Hamiltonian cycle, from which we can delete any edge and get a Hamiltonian path. Case 3 isn't too hard either; the vertices of degree three are the beginning and the end of the trail, so delete the first edge and last edge and get a Hamiltonian path.